# Is there any software to install for terracotta client?

Tags: terracotta

I want to work one machine as terracotta client.

Does I need to install any  software to make a mcahine terracotta client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terracotta software must be installed on all servers and clients. Their [documentation](http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/) gives plenty of details on how to set this up.